# SetSecurityInfo fails for PROCESS_TERMINATE

Tags: windows, winapi

I am trying to set security of PROCESS_TERMINATE. This is the code:

```
   CreateProcess("C:\\ADP\\SQLBase\\dbntsrv.exe", NULL, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_NO_WINDOW, NULL, "C:\\ADP\\SQLBase", &si, &pi);       

if(SetSecurityInfo(pi.hProcess, SE_KERNEL_OBJECT, PROCESS_TERMINATE, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "process_terminate granted", NULL, MB_OK);
}
else
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "process_terminate not granted", NULL, MB_OK);
}



                    //--------------------- Permission to query for info to use GetExitCode -------------------------
if(SetSecurityInfo(pi.hProcess, SE_KERNEL_OBJECT, PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL) == ERROR_SUCCESS)
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "process_query_information granted", NULL, MB_OK);
}
else
{
    MessageBox(NULL, "process_query_information not granted", NULL, MB_OK);
}


LPDWORD lpExitCode;
GetExitCodeProcess(pi.hProcess, lpExitCode);
```

Here SetSecurityInfo for for PROCESS_TERMINATE fails and I get an `Unhandled Exception..(KERNEL32.dll):Access Violation` for

```
GetExitCodeProcess(pi.hProcess, lpExitCode);
```

Why does this happen? Thank You

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The access violation is because of this code:

```
LPDWORD lpExitCode;
GetExitCodeProcess(pi.hProcess, lpExitCode);
```

Here you declare that `lpExitCode` is a pointer, but you don't make it point at anything. When `GetExitCodeProcess` tries to write to `*lpExitCode` it results in an access violation.

The correct approach is like this:

```
DWORD ExitCode;
GetExitCodeProcess(pi.hProcess, &ExitCode);
```

I also don't believe that you need to call `SetSecurityInfo` at all. The process handle that `CreateProcess` returns should have sufficient rights.

You will need to wait for the spawned process to terminate before you can expect to get an exit code. This is because `GetExitCodeProcess` is asynchronous. You can wait like this:

```
WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess);
//now you can call GetExitCodeProcess and expect an answer.
```

And do remember to check all your API calls for errors.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the incorect call to `GetExitCodeProcess`, your call to `SetSecurityInfo` is also incorrect. `PROCESS_TERMINATE` is not a valid value for the third parameter. According to [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379588%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), valid values for the third parameter are

> OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION: Include the owner.
>
> GROUP_SECURITY_INFORMATION: Include the primary group.
>
> DACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION: Include the discretionary access control list (DACL).
>
> SACL_SECURITY_INFORMATION: Include the system access control list (SACL).
>
> LABEL_SECURITY_INFORMATION: Include the mandatory integrity label access control entry (ACE).
>
> ATTRIBUTE_SECURITY_INFORMATION: Include the attribute information of the SACL.
>
> SCOPE_SECURITY_INFORMATION: Include the central access policy (CAP) identifier of the SACL.

Your value of `PROCESS_TERMINATE` happens to be numerically equal to `OWNER_SECURITY_INFORMATION` so your call is actually trying to change the process owner (but does it incorrectly, which is why the call fails).